# How to got the columns value in textbooks in java script

Tags: javascript

I need to know How to got the columns value in textbooks  in java script

in my code i got only the value for the first and second columns only and i need to got the value also for the third and Four columns 
please fine my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function OnGridFocusedRowChanged() {
         // Query the server for the "EmployeeID" and "Notes" fields from the focused row 
         // The values will be returned to the OnGetRowValues() function
         // DetailNotes.SetText("Loading...");
         grid.GetRowValues(grid.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'Bank_ID;OrderRef;Name;Center', OnGetRowValues);

     }
     // Value array contains "EmployeeID" and "Notes" field values returned from the server 
     function OnGetRowValues(values) {


         //   DetailNotes.SetText(values[1]);
         ASPxTextBox1.SetText(values[1]);
         ASPxTextBox2.SetText(values[0]);
         ASPxTextBox3.SetText(values[2]);
         ASPxTextBox4.SetText(values[3]);
     }

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeout;
    function scheduleGridUpdate(grid) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = window.setTimeout(
            function () { grid.Refresh(); },
            5000
        );
    }
    function grid_Init(s, e) {
        scheduleGridUpdate(s);
    }
    function grid_BeginCallback(s, e) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    function grid_EndCallback(s, e) {
        scheduleGridUpdate(s);
    }
</script>
```